# how to not expose a class to any other class but one? (C#)

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, encapsulation

I have a namespace ABC, which has one form class, F and an ordinary class C. Now I have another namespace XYZ with many different classes. Now, F is used only from C and nowhere else in the program. Every other classes use C, not F.

In visual studio (2010), from classes in XYZ namespace I can see F listed in the intellisense dropdown (since I've referenced ABC to use C). How can I prevent that?I want only C there. Any method would suffice as long as I can use C from XYZ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't put it in another namespace to hide it from the other classes, e.g. namespace ABC.Forms ?

If it were anything other than a form class (therefore is a partial class if you are using a recent version of .net) - I would say, why not make it an inner class to C - but I doubt that would be neat with a form class.

I would go with the namespace change.

Comment: No I dont want to move ABC to another namespace. I have no problem in making form class inner class to C, but is it possible with a form class?

Comment: Mmm, if the form class is entirely code and not made through the Visual Studio designers then I see no reason why not.  However I guess that this is not the case, in which case the form is split into two partial classes, and you can't just embed a bit of it as a nested class inside C.

Comment: Yes your are right, its split into two classes, but i dont mind making it one. I think I can include all the initializing part to one class.Thanks for your help

Comment: You might stop visual studio being able to add controls and events to your form class - but if you don't mind that then go ahead and try it out.

Answer (score 5):

Can you make F a nested class inside of your C class?

```
public class C
{
    public C()
    { }

    class F : Form
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this works for your scenario, but it would solve the Intellisense problem, while satisfying the requirements listed above.

Comment: I can do that, but is it possible for a form class?

Comment: @nawfal: Yes it can be done for a Form. It is just another class. I see your comment in iandotkelly's answer about the partial class problem. You can always combine the partial classes into a single class to make your life easier. This would make the Form class look more like the ones generated in Visual Studio 2005, where you could use a region instead of a separate file to hide away the designer generated code.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for your help. Now confused who has given the right answer as you both have, and also the same one! :)

Comment: @nawfal, this is definitely my preferred answer to this.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yes. But since @iandotkelly came up with the answer slightly quicker and both the answer being the same, let me vote for him..